# Java compiler can not find symbol - public class in same package

Tags: java, eclipse

I've got a problem with a Main class not finding another class being public, in the same folder and the same package. Both classes are named as their files. Here is the part seeming to contain the problem:

The Interface:

```
package hanoi;

public interface Stack<E> {

...

}
```

The Over-Class:

```
package hanoi;

public class DefaultStack<E> implements Stack<E> {

...

}
```

The Used class:

```
package hanoi;

public class HanoiStack extends DefaultStack<HanoiDisk> {

    public HanoiStack (int a){

        for (int b = a; b > 0; b--){

            HanoiDisk disk = new HanoiDisk(b);

            this.push(disk);

        }

    }
...
}
```

Main Class:

```
package hanoi;

public class TowersOfHanoi{

    HanoiStack stack1 = new HanoiStack(0);
    HanoiStack stack2 = new HanoiStack(0);
    HanoiStack stack3 = new HanoiStack(0);
...

}
```

File Directory (of both):

```
...\eclipse\Hanoi2\src\hanoi

Eclipse error: Main class could either not be found or not be loaded
```

(there is actually a main method in the main class, but the rest of the code gets very complicated and doesnt seem to be interesting right now)

```
Java Compiler error: could nor find symbol: class HanoiStack
```

Another hint: a friend of mine is working on the same project, seeming toi have declared the interesting part same as me but not having any issues.

Update: download link to the full program [is here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/34761768/Hanoi2.zip)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like either Eclipse playing up, or it cant compile the classes for some reason.

1) Clean the project in Eclipse. (Project -> Clean -> Clean all projects) Then restart Eclipse for good measure.

2) Check the folder where the project is configured to build is writable.  To check what this is, view the project build path (right click -> Build Path -> Configure build path) under source tab check the output folder.

If neither of these help, could you provide more info where the main class is. E.g. is it in the TowersOfHanoi class?

Comment: 1) didn't work

2) where exactly? tried multiple ways but cant find build path (right click file > source > ? or (at the top of the window) source > ?)

3) Thank you!

Comment: eddited the question so you can download the whole programm, maybe there is a problem with the folder konstruktion/ one in the other files... or someone can tell me if it works with his eclipse configuration... every help would be awesome!